# Appropriate way to write this equation of linear norm

Tags: normed-spaces

Assume a continuous and bounded functions $x : \mathbf R \to \mathbf C$, $x(t) \not= 0$ only if $a \leq t \leq b$ and that $|x(t)| \leq 1$ for all $t$. 
So the signal is finite.

I have mappings:

\begin{equation}
Aux_{\tau} : L^{2}(\mathbf{R}) \times L^{2}(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R})
\end{equation}

and 
\begin{equation}
A : L^{2}(\mathbf{R}) \rightarrow L^{2}(\mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R})
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}
A(x)(t,f) = \int Aux_{\tau} (x)(t,f) d\tau,
\end{equation}

choosing $x=y$ for $Aux_{\tau}$, we get their norm by Schwartz inequality

### #1

\begin{equation}
\lVert A(x) \rVert_{L^{2}( \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R} )}
\leq \int \lVert Aux_{\tau}(x) \rVert_{L^{2}( \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R} )} d\tau.
\end{equation}

The mapping is not a contraction mapping.
I do not want to confuse the reader.
I have seen some people writing the last equation by ignoring the spaces as

### #2

\begin{equation}
\lVert A(x) \rVert_{L^{2}(\mathbf R) \to L^2(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)}
\leq \int \lVert Aux_{\tau}(x) \rVert_{L^{2}(\mathbf R) \to L^2(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)} d\tau.
\end{equation}

### #3

\begin{equation}
\lVert A(x) \rVert_{L^{2}(\mathbf R) \to L^2(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R) }
\leq \int \lVert Aux_{\tau}(x) \rVert_{L^{2}(\mathbf R) \times L^2(\mathbf R) \to L^2(\mathbf R \times \mathbf R)} d\tau.
\end{equation}

### #4

\begin{equation}
\lVert A(x) \rVert_{L^2}
\leq \int \lVert Aux_{\tau}(x) \rVert_{L^2} d\tau.
\end{equation}

**What is the appropriate way of writing the inequality?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

\begin{equation}
\lVert Ax \rVert_{L^{2}\to L^2}
\leq \int \lVert Aux_{\tau}(x) \rVert_{L^{2}\to L^2} d\tau.
\end{equation}

the main point being that $Ax$ is not an element of $L^2$, but a mapping from $L^2$ to itself.

That is, if I am understanding correctly what you wrote.

Comment: Except in the original question you say $Aux_\tau:L^2(\mathbb R) \times L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$.  So shouldn't it be $\|Aux_\tau\|_{L^2(\mathbb R) \times L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)}$?

Comment: What does the $(x)$ in $Aux_\tau(x)$ mean?

Comment: x is a continuous and bounded function in $Aux_{\tau}(x)$ and $Ax := A(x)$. I added the definition of the signal in the body of my question.

Comment: In that case I suppose (2) is correct.

Comment: **How do you think (2) is correct?** I think (2) cannot be correct because of the definition of $Aux_{\tau}$ now.I think (3) and (1) are only correct. I think (1) is the clearest because the subscript describes the results of the mappings which are in the inequality.

Comment: Well, $Aux_\tau$ is a function of two inputs $x,y \in L^2$.  But now you have filled one of the input slots with $x$.  So what you should have inside the norm is really $Aux_\tau(x,\cdot)$.  That is, if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: (1) cannot be correct.  Because it implies that $Ax$ is in $L^2$.  But it isn't.  It is a function from $L^2 \to L^2$.

Comment: Look this is the easiest: $\|Ax(y)\|_{L^2} \le \int \|Aux_\tau(x,y)\|_{L^2} \, d\tau$.

Comment: So $Aux_{\tau}(x,x) := Aux_{\tau}(x)$ when $x=y$. **Do you think your last proposed is still the most appropriate one?**

Comment: **What do you think about (3)?** I have sometimes such expressions that is not from $L^2$ to $L^2$. In that case, I think $L^2$ would not work since it is a mapping from $\mathscr S \to L^2$ for instance. I think (3) is probably the most clearest when we think that we do not always have from the $L^2$ to $L^2$.

Comment: But with my new understanding of what you wrote, (3) is wrong.  Because now I see that $Aux_\tau(x)$ is an element of $L^2$.  So it must be (1) that is correct.  But now $Ax$ is not an operator, but a function in $L^2$.  Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes. $A(x) := Ax$ which is a function in $L^2$. I added your proposal to 4th. I think also that (1) is correct. **What do you think is now the most appropriate one?**

Comment: Either (1) or (4).  But (1) conveys more information.